# MSVC++ 2013 seems to allow assignments to temporary objects, effectively treating them as lvalues

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013, rvalue-reference, lvalue

I've come across this "feature" in MSVC++ and I'm now not sure if it's a bug or my understanding of lvalues/rvalues in C++ is just plain wrong.

I've added some seriously dumbed-down code to illustrate, but basically the issue is that MSVC++ 2013 (both base and NOV 2013 CTP compilers) allows assignment to temporary objects, which should really be rvalues and hence disallow any assignment attempts at compile time.

```
#include <iostream>

struct account {
    int value;

    explicit account(int v) : value{ v } { 
        std::cout << "account ctor: " << value << std::endl; 
    }
    account(const account & acc) : value{ acc.value } { 
        std::cout << "account copy ctor" << std::endl; 
    }
    account(account && acc) : value{ acc.value } { 
        std::cout << "account move ctor" << std::endl; 
    }
    account & operator=(const account & acc) {
        value = acc.value;
        std::cout << "account copy assign" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
    account & operator=(account && acc) {
        value = acc.value;
        std::cout << "account move assign" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }   
};

int get_int() { return 42; }

account get_account() {
    return account(123);
}

int main() {
    //get_int() = 5;    // this predictably fails to compile
                        // with '=' : left operand must be l-value

    // everything below succeeds
    get_account() = account(42);    // console trace for this 
                                    // account ctor: 42
                                    // account ctor: 123
                                    // account move assign

    account(123) = account(42);     // console trace same as above

    account acc(0);                 // account ctor: 0
    account(42) = acc;              // account ctor: 42
                                    // account copy assign

    get_account() = acc;            // console trace same as above
}
```

Surely `get_account() = acc;` or `account(42) = acc;` is not C++ Standard's prescribed behaviour?! Both `get_account()` & `account(42)` should result in rvalues, which by definition do not allow assignments.

Incidentally, overloading member functions based on lvalue/rvalue qualifiers

```
...
void memberFn() const &;
void memberFn() &&;
...
```

which is supported in NOV 2013 CTP is not working properly or at all. I assume this is a result of failing to recognise rvalues, so that `this` is always an lvalue.

PS Unfortunately, I do not have an opportunity to test this with other compilers.

Comment: Here it is running on gcc 5.1: [http://ideone.com/08GbjA](http://ideone.com/08GbjA)

Comment: I guess your confusion roots in the different meaning of pre-C++11 "rvalues" (in contrast to lvalues) and post-C++11 (p)rvalues (in contrast to glvalues, xvalues, rvalues, lvalues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, this is perfectly valid C++11.

Only **built-in assignment** to prvalues is prohibited.

From [5, expr]:

> Note: Operators can be overloaded, that is, given meaning when applied to expressions of class type (Clause
>   9) or enumeration type (7.2). Uses of overloaded operators are transformed into function calls as described
>   in 13.5. Overloaded operators obey the rules for syntax specified in Clause 5, but the requirements of
>   operand type, **value category**, and evaluation order are replaced by the rules for function call.

So the requirements on

```
get_account() = account(42);
```

are the same as on any other member-function call

```
get_account().foo_bar(account(42));
```

which makes sense since it is just a nicer syntax for

```
get_account().operator=(account(42));
```

The section 3.10 on Lvalues and rvalues makes this as clear well [basic.lval]:

> For example, the built-in assignment operators expect that the left operand is an lvalue and that the right operand is a prvalue and yield an lvalue as the result. User-defined operators are functions, and the categories of values they expect and yield are determined by their parameter and return
>   types.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks a million for clarifying this!